# errors in missMDA function

Tags: r

I'm actually working on an end-studies project on stallion fertility.
And so, I have few factors that I would like to test their effect on stallion fertility.
I have a large table with 54 columns and about 300 rows, each column is a factor, either quantitative or qualitative. The fertility is transcript by "yes" or "non" in the column "DG".
So to test all factors and maybe interactions, I would like to do an AFDM analysis but before that, I have to run missMDA function because I have empty values.
But, when I try to do missMDA function, have always error messages as for exemple :

```
> res.impute<-imputeFAMD(Tableau_analyse_juments_finies, ncp = 3)
Error in eigen(crossprod(X, X), symmetric = TRUE) : 0 x 0 matrix

> res.impute<-estim_ncpFAMD(Tableau_analyse_juments_finies)
Error in `[.data.frame`(jeu, , (nbquanti + 1):ncol(jeu), drop = F) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I'm not very good in statistics and statisticians from my school don't have time to help me so I'm embarrassed. Could someone help me?

PS : I'm French so if someone is French as well, he can speak me French, it will be easier for me :)

Comment: Bien venue a SO, with a little data we can help more, `dput(head(your_data, n = 10))`. For a preliminary view you might want to try `your_data_complete <- your_data[complete.cases(your_data), ]` that will remove rows with missing values then run AFDM on the complete cases. As an initial. Then you can decide if you want to go back and impute missing values with a better sense of what a good imput might be, e pardon a moi, je ne pa le pa francias.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Chris, I answered you below because it's too long

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found out that all character variables need to be converted to factor. For all character variables, convert them using `as.factor()`.

Answer (score 0):

When I do dput function, I have this :

```
structure(list(Jument = c("Darling-de-Courcy", "Darling-de-Courcy", 
"Doublette", "Undoctra-d-Helby", "Unfee-du-Clos-Marman", "Hadelle-de-Padoue", 
"Prunelle-de-la-Vallee", "Prunelle-de-la-Vallee", "Quelle-dame-du-Mesnil", 
"Quiara-de-Saint-A"), Etalon = c("ARMITAGES", "ARMITAGES", "ARMITAGES", 
"ARMITAGES", "ARMITAGES", "BY-CERA", "BY-CERA", "BY-CERA", "CANTURANO", 
"CANTURANO"), Age = c(7, 7, 17, 12, 12, 3, 17, 17, 16, 16), Historique = c("S", 
"S", "P", "TE-2019", "MPNS", "P", "MPNS", "MPNS", "P", "MPNS"
), `NEC-1` = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Antecedents = c("Poulin", 
"Poulin", "Compet", "Compet", "Poulin", "Elevage", "Poulin", 
"Poulin", "Compet", "Poulin"), Habitat = c("PT", "PT", "PI", 
"Box", "PT", "PT", "PT", "PT", "PT", "PT"), `Nb-chaleurs` = c(2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), Lait = c("oui", "oui", "non", "non", 
"non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non"), `TM-1` = c("IAR", 
"IAR", "IAR", "IAR", "IAC", "IAC", "IAR-12", "IAR-12", "IAR", 
"IAR"), `N.-inse-1` = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), D1 = structure(c(1586390400, 
1588204800, 1586390400, 1585958400, 1588896000, 1587772800, 1584489600, 
1586304000, 1587600000, 1584144000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), H1 = c("MA", "MA", "AM", "MA", "M", "M", "AM", "AM", 
"AM", "MA"), `N.-paillettes-1` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), I1 = c(6, 6, 12, 24, 0, 24, 48, 24, 24, 6), Mob1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.8), CC1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 303, 234), `N.-Saut-1` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, 1), `Gel-1` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0, 1), `DG-1` = c("non", "oui", "oui", "oui", "oui", "oui", "non", 
"oui", "oui", "non")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But I have the impress that R consider each stallion ("Etalon" in my database), as an unique individual, but for exemple the stallion "ARMITAGES" reproduced many mares ("Jument" in my database).

When I try to do your function for missing values, my database become empty and they are no data anymore.

Comment: When I retry to do the function imputeFAMD, I have this 
```Error in apply(tabdisj[, (vec[i] + 1):vec[i + 1]], 1, which.max) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length```

Comment: Hi, you can edit your question and put the addtional information there (and delete the answer as it’s not really an answer). The question will be much more readable in that way :)